MSI laptop started stinking
My MSI MS-16P7 gaming laptop from 2018 started reeking of cigarettes weeks after upgrading it from 16 to 64 GB RAM, 256 GB to 1TB NVME, and 1TB HDD to 2TB SSD. I notice there are brown patches on the heat pipes which neither a moist towel nor my nail can wipe off, possibly from the darkened motherboard area around the NVME. I don't smoke, but did notice the fan intakes were dusty, which explains why my GPU went to 100 instead of 70 degrees Celsius during LLM inference. Limiting the processors to 95% helped temps stay under 80 according to GPU-Z, but the smell lingers despite lessening. What to do? Replace the very sticky and possibly sweaty thermal pads with one long new one and blast the smellier fans with compressed air despite not seeing dust in them?


On closer inspection, it appears that the draft sealing pads right on top of the right exhaust and heat pipe near the left exhaust are falling apart. I guess sucking in exhaust is better than pieces of sticky pad.

It also appears that the thermal interface material has leaked on one side of the main heat sink. I don't know when that happened or whether that caused the max 100 degrees Celsius of my CPU under load.


Do not use compressed air or a vacuum cleaner on fans, especially if they are still plugged in. Excessive speed can cause voltage spikes and also damage bearings. // Are you sure the fans are even working? Do you hear them, does air flow?

@DanielB The fans work fine, especially while using the manual turbo switch which I used for days after discovering the stench came from my laptop burning dust or something instead of outside which I suspected after a busy festival on the 27th of April.

@John After ruining some outdoor paintjobs using WD-40, and melting my printer with whatever is in HG sticker remover, I'm hesitant to expose my hardware to chemicals. The NVME and (sealed) heat pipe stains were already present when upgrading the RAM on 2024-01-10, and given the pattern and function, is probably from heat difference in the metal due to internal condensation, so natural. I can remove the degraded sealing pads but the mobo stain near the thermal pads worries me.

The degraded sealing pads are made of oil, but the brown areas do not match their location, only those of decreasing temperature, and I rarely have visitors who smoke. Only the central heatsink area and radial fan areas stink. What about the thermal pads and stain there?

I am a bit lost here. Did you upgrade it or did someone else? If it was you, I would be surprised that you did not notice when you upgraded it. Secondly, is this a secondhand machine?

@Bib I bought it in 2018 and upgraded it late 2023/begin 2024. Most humans don't notice things when not looking for them. Before, during, and right after the upgrade there was no stink so no reason to suspect anything.

Thermal pads contain silicone oil that conducts heat but not electricity. They last about 5 years.
According to this video, 84 (15 W/mK) to 98 (stock pads) degrees Celsius is normal for a video card at 100%, but a Samsung SSD should stay between 30 and 50 degrees Celsius under load. They throttle at 70.
SpeedFan 4.52 says my NVME drive (HD1. Temp1 is CPU) is 50+ degrees Celsius while browsing with the manual fan boost off, so I'm looking into a new pad that should fit better physically and conductivity-wise and doesn't compress too much (more than 30%). Until then it's fan noise for me. SpeedFan considers 37C low for HD and 38C low for CPU.

As for the stench, since removing the dust lessened it, it was probably dust. I've removed the degraded sealing pads just in case (using 96% alcohol which is too strong for pressed CD labels) as it's better to suck in air near the bottom like it was designed to, than sticky decaying plastic, which might also explain the burning smell. So far it still smells old but doesn't stink anymore.
Update 2024-05-20: After it refused to sleep last night, but the fans were fortunately still boosted, and watching YouTube for a couple of hours, the hottest sensor is 45C CPU. But even with an open window + large fan, and no component feeling warm or looking dusty, the stench is back. Maybe MSI plastic (no rattle) or dust (none visible) or a blown capacitor (guess i'll try to remove the mobo) degrades at 50C.
Update 2024-05-21: I didn't feel like messing with all the screws and heatpipe connections, so just disconnected the fans and hit them with compressed air. Seems to have stopped the poplar seed stink and despite one crash due to overheating:
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power" Guid="{331c3b3a-2005-44c2-ac5e-77220c37d6b4}" /> 
  <EventID>86</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>83</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x8000000000000020</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2024-05-21T18:05:45.4845791Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>45870</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="15772" /> 
  <Channel>System</Channel> 
  <Computer>MSI</Computer> 
  <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data Name="ThermalZoneDeviceInstanceLength">9</Data> 
  <Data Name="ThermalZoneDeviceInstance">\_TZ.THRM</Data> 
  <Data Name="ShutdownTime">2024-05-21T18:05:45.4840604Z</Data> 
  <Data Name="_CRT">373</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>

I just played some more Doom (2016) and with the fan boost on, max temps were only up to 70C iirc. HWiNFo is better than SpeedFan at keeping track of max temps, so I'll use that next time.
Update 2024-05-28: The thermal pad under the NVMe ASIC was misaligned according to my King of Crabs session with about 90 open YouTube tabs. I think the buffering writes from those (Google blocks blocking YouTube tabs from loading for "performance") overheated the ASIC.

Fixing that and putting a thin YAODHAOD M.2 graphite/copper sticker on the bottom and an ARCTIC TP-3 thermal pad + another sticker on top appears to have worked (13C improvement):

Not sure why the PCH isn't reading. Maybe I accidentally zapped it while doing more fan cleaning with my new Chanurae duster, but then other stuff should probably not work either. Turns out that's an EUFI bug according to this thread.
Right now I smell only rain from outside. Feels good.
